# Database for saving date span

Tags: mysql, database, algorithm, postgresql

I have a question generally about database design.

I need to store price for different room types for different hotels for different dates. The date could be a interval or it could be specific weekdays during that time interval, and the interval is totally random.

So there are two solutions I try to evaluate:

1. Store price for each day. The problem would be we have like over 3,000 different hotels, so in the end the price table would contain more than 10 million lines.
2. Store date for a whole year as a byte array, each bit represents 1 day. So each row for a price would include the entire time interval the price is valid for. The problem for this would be how to index the date byte array, and how fast the search would be; and the handling of transfer price you enter to the correct format.

Which solution should I go for? I haven’t tried anything and don’t know about how different database handles different scenarios and how indexing of a byte array (string) works for bitwise operation compare and so on. Any other suggestion is welcome.

Comment: In case (2), how do you make sure that for a given date and place, you don't have many prices? You need to do a binary `and` on every existing rows to avoid overlaps.

Comment: If from 1–7 July a room costs £100, and 8–14 July a room costs £150, but I book in from say, 4-10 July, what rate will I be charged?

Comment: you will be charged for each day

Comment: in case 2, there for the question is how does db have support for indexed byte array that is used in bitwise operation, so indexing never works in bitwise operation

Comment: "the price table would contain more than 10 million lines" - and that would be a problem because...?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have also tagged this with PostgreSQL, the new interval data type introduced in 9.2 seems like a good (and efficient) fit here:

A simplified example would look like this:

```
create table room_price
(
   room_id       integer       not null,
   hotel_id      integer       not null,
   price         numeric(16,4) not null,
   valid_during  daterange not null
);
```

Then you can insert something like this:

```
insert into room_price 
  (room_id, hotel_id, price, valid_during)
values 
  (1, 1, 100.0, '[2014-07-01,2014-07-01]'),
  (1, 1,  90.0, '[2014-07-02,2014-07-12]');
```

The `[...]` notation defines an interval that includes both dates (`[..)` would define an interval that excludes the left edge).

You can very easily query the above table to get the price for a specific room on a specific date:

```
select *
from room_price
where room_id = 1
  and valid_during @> date '2014-07-04;
```

would return the price with 90.0

You can even define a constraint that prevents overlapping dates:

```
alter table room_price
  add constraint check_price_range 
  exclude using gist (room_id with =, valid_during with &&)
```

With the above constraint Postgres would reject the following insert:

```
insert into room_price
  (room_id, hotel_id, price, valid_during)
values 
  (1,  90.0, '[2014-07-03,2014-07-04]');
```

The constraint implicitly creates an index on the table which is used to lookup the data and thus makes queries quite efficient.

Comment: The problem with this design would be how to match a time interval that matches over several rows, and how to certainly change add new price that overlaps with the older price time interval.

Comment: *data type integer has no default operator class for access method "gist"* by default: you can use the `btree_gist` module, or define the exclude constraint with `exclude using gist (int4range(room_id, room_id, '[]') with &&, valid_during with &&)`

Comment: @user2412555 here is an example, how to query through multiple ranges (with different prices): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4b69f/8 -- why do you want to add new prices that overlaps with the older prices?

Comment: @user2412555 but that's just an update, right? A single date cannot have multiple price with that concept too. At least that wouldn't make much sense to me.

Comment: you can have this scenarior, first from 1/1 to 1/3 you have price 500, then they updated that on 1/2, they have another price of 400 for some campaign,

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL has a pair of features specifically designed for this kind of thing: range types and exclusion constraints.

Store the prices with validity as a range, or set of ranges. Then define exclusion constraints to make sure there's no overlap where two prices are valid for a given place/time.

Unfortunately ranges can't be sparse (have holes) so whether this works for you will depend a bit on the data patterns.

To learn more:

- [range types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rangetypes.html)
- [exclusion constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION)